# Command line windows

Tags: windows, go, cmd, nmap

I am just trying to run an nmap scan on my system using Go with below main function

```
func main() {

execErr := exec.Command("cmd","/c","nmap -T4 -A -v localhost")
if execErr != nil {
panic(execErr)
}

}
```

Its panicking. I tried to search documentation online but could not find anything helpful for windows yet. Can someone help or point to some resources?

Answer (score 2):

[`exec.Command()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Command) does not return an `error` but [`*Cmd`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#Cmd) type struct on which you then can call a method [`Run()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#example_Cmd_Run) (or other methods, see NOTE below) to execute the command like this:

```golang
cmd := exec.Command("cmd","/c","nmap -T4 -A -v localhost")
err := cmd.Run()
if execErr != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

Your code `panic`s because `exec.Command("cmd","/c","nmap -T4 -A -v localhost")` returns a valid non-nil pointer to `Cmd` struct (panic message is likely full path to the `cmd.exe` and then arguments you provided which are values of fields `Path` and `Args` of `Cmd` struct...).

NOTE: It is not good practice to `panic()` here, use `log.Fatal()` instead. Also it might be better to run `nmap` directly and process its output in code. See examples of reading other command output using [`Output()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#example_Cmd_Output), [`CombinedOutput()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#example_Cmd_CombinedOutput) and [`Start()`](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#example_Cmd_Start) depending on what you are trying to do and how command behaves.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am trying to build an nmap scanner using golang where I take user input from an HTML form in a text box and run the nmap scan for that host/IP

`cmd,err := exec.Command(`C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap\nmap.exe`, "nmap -T4 -A -v localhost").Output()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)

}
fmt.Printf("The output is %s\n", cmd)
}`  

This code gives the below output 

`The output is Starting Nmap 7.91 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2021-01-17 22:21 Eastern Standard Time`

It starts but doesnt wait to complete

Comment: I tried using `run()` as the alternative but that doesnt give any output at all

Comment: I believe you have nmap twice in your commandline so nmap fails to parse arguments and outputs error on stderr which you don't see because `Output()` only captures standard out (but not err) of the process. Your invocation should be `exec.Command("path\to\nmap.exe", "-T4 -A..."). I am not familiar with `nmap` at all but if it is somehow interactive process you'll probably have to attach to it's `std*` pipes using `Cmd.Std*Pipe()` functions. See the docs I linked in my reply, it's all there.